# VS Code: How can I enable format-on-save for .cpp files but not .h?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

There's a ticket open here for having extension specific settings: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35350

But it's still open. So I'm wondering, is there a hack or workaround or plugin that can do what I want?

Alternatively, I'd be ok (for now) with being able to enable format-on-save in a specific folder, but have it disabled in general.

(We use clang-format but presumably that doesn't really matter)